SemaphoreUI - Issues with remote (Azure DevOps) and local repositories
I installed SemaphoreUI using Snap on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
I want to run an Ansible playbook that is in a git repository in Azure DevOps.
I configured the repository in SemaphoreUI, I tried both with HTTPS and SSH, I added the credentials and the SSH key in the Key store, but I'm not able to git clone from Azure DevOps.
If I try with HTTPS, the error is:
cloning Repository https://dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx/_git/semaphoreui-automation
Unable to clone repository: unexpected client error: unexpected requesting "https://xxx:xxx@dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx/_git/semaphoreui-automation/git-upload-pack" status code: 400
4:37:19 PM
Failed updating repository: unexpected client error: unexpected requesting "https://xxx:xxx@dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx/_git/semaphoreui-automation/git-upload-pack" status code: 400
4:37:19 PM
Running app failed: unexpected client error: unexpected requesting "https://xxx:xxx@dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx/_git/semaphoreui-automation/git-upload-pack" status code: 400

If I try with SSH, using the URL suggested by Azure DevOps, the error is:
Cloning Repository git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/xxx/xxx/semaphoreui-automation
Unable to clone repository: object not found
Failed updating repository: object not found

Finally, I tried with ssh://, as suggested by the Semaphore doc, but still I have an error:
Cloning Repository ssh://ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/xxx/xxx/semaphoreui-automation
Unable to clone repository: parse "ssh://ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/xxx/xxx/semaphoreui-automation": invalid port ":v3" after host
Failed updating repository: parse "ssh://ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/xxx/xxx/semaphoreui-automation": invalid port ":v3" after host

Then, I tried to use a local path and a git local repository.
For the local path the error is:
Failed in finding static repository at /opt/git/semaphoreui-automation: stat /opt/git/semaphoreui-automation: no such file or directory

Whereas for the git local repository the error which appears is:
Unable to clone repository: exec: "git": executable file not found in $PATH

As far as I understand, these two last issues are due to the use of the Snap. Can you confirm that if I reinstall everything using the package instead of the snap, I will be able to use the local repositories?
Is it possible that every possible repositories fails?
Can you help me to make one repository work?

Not sure if this can be helpful, but take a look: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops

Can you specify how you setup your environment to reproduce the issue? Any document you referenced rather than a single sentence I installed SemaphoreUI using Snap on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS..

Hi @kkk, Welcome to SO. May I know if you are able to clone any GitHub repo like https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/pipelines-dotnet-core or the issue only occurred to Azure Repos? Thx for the details to help isolate the root cause.

Hi @AlvinZhao-MSFT I'm able to clone the GitHub repo you linked.
Cloning Repository https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/pipelines-dotnet-core
Enumerating objects: 333, done.
Total 333 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 333 (from 1)

Since you are able to clone the Azure Repos on the server machine, there seems nothing much that we can do from the Azure DevOps perspective. And by default, git is installed on ubuntu OS. Please edit your original post and let the community experts know how you installed SemaphoreUI to reproduce this issue. And share any SemaphoreUI document you referenced to ingerate git on ubuntu if possible.

To resolve exec: "git": executable file not found in $PATH you'd better install git on your server. It is not included with Semaphore.
I cloned such an URL for my Azure DevOps git repository with SSH in Semaphore:
git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/org/project/repo

I had to add my private key to the Semaphore Keystore, and reference it as Access Key when defining the repository.

Git is installed on my server.
But the thing is that from the snap installation, SemaphoreUI can't see the Git installed on the server as Semaphore is installed in restricted mode. But what would be the right approach then?

So you are able to clone Azure DevOps repo on the server machine? The failure only occurs in  SemaphoreUI, probably because SemaphoreUI from the snap installation can't see the Git installed on the server?

Yes, I am able to clone Azure DevOps directly on the server machine. I'm not able to do it from SemaphoreUI. The error logged with GIT occurred when I try to use a local repository. Not the Azure DevOps one. With Azure I got these two errors: Unable to clone repository: unexpected client error: unexpected requesting "https://xxx:xxx@dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx/_git/semaphoreui-automation/git-upload-pack" status code: 400 (HTTPS) and Unable to clone repository: object not found (SSH)
